# Android Libdgx loading files during splash screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I'm currently working on an android project in which I'm making a game using libgdx. I've created a splash screen which shows up in the beginning for a second, but it doesn't do any file loading currently. The problem I'm having is that when I'm loading the files like the music and sound files, they are all loaded once I hit play. Because there are a decent number of sound files it's takes a while to load the game after someone hits play. My question is there anyway to move the loading of these files to the splash screen? For those familiar with libgdx and android studio, currently my splash screen code is in a separate module under "android" and the rest of the program is under "core" (separate module core). When I try initializing the sound files in the core module I can't access them in the core module which makes sense considering they are different modules all together and I can't move the android module which does the splash screen and such into core because then I would lose the android studio setup that is made. If I can't load the files earlier in the program is there any way to load them faster upon game start? I'm sorry if my question isn't clear enough.. I'm trying to be as clear as I can be.

Also when I try to use say a thread and then load files with libgdx using say:

```
atk1 = (Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/fight/attack1.wav")));
```

Here the sounds are in the assets folder. I keep getting an error when I try doing it in the android module but no issues when doing it in core. Why can't I load them in the android manager like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loading screen in between, after splash and before actual game. Use a [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) to load all of them and keep there reference alive.

But i would recommend moving splash screen to core and load when the splash screen is displayed in background. You can still access android methods from core if you want to by creating an interface and it looks better that way.